# In R how to convert Longitude and Latitude to a format that can be used in ggplot2 or ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, coordinates, geography, ggmap

I got a raw Longitude/Latitude data whose format cannot be processed by R map. So I wonder if there are some R functions or algorithms to help me to convert those raw data into a readable format. (Maybe UTM) Here is the raw data I had:

**Latitude:**
"32-14-23 N" "31-04-27 N" "33-45-28 N"

**Longitude:**
"121-22-38 W"    "119-30-05 W"    "122-47-52 W"

I wish to convert the format as(the sample below is mock data):

**Longitude:**     -2.748

**Latitude:**       53.39

Comment: What's your formula for converting the raw data to those float values?

Comment: That's what I am asking. Any algorithm or R packages that can help?

Comment: I am asking if you can explain in words what rules you are using to convert your data? How does the raw data for longitude correspond to the -2.748 value?

Comment: @Synergist Just modified the question. The -2.748 value is mock data. There is no relationship between -2.748 and the raw data above. I am just using -2.748 to show the data format I want.

Answer (score 17):

Looks like you have data in degree / minute / second format and you want it in decimal format. You can use the `char2dms` function in the `sp` package to go from character string to a degree-minute-second object, and then use `as.numeric` to convert to decimal

Example:

```
> as.numeric(sp::char2dms("32d14'23\"N"))
[1] 32.23972
> as.numeric(sp::char2dms("121d22'38\" W"))
[1] -121.3772
```

Also note `char2dms` is looking for something like `32d14'23" N`, not `32-14-23 N`, so you may have to assemble the proper string. Using a `magrittr` pipe chain:

```
"32-14-23 N" %>%
  sub('-', 'd', .) %>%
  sub('-', '\'', .) %>%
  sub(' ', '" ', .) %>%
  char2dms %>%
  as.numeric
```