# Convert to decimal degrees using birk library in R

Tags: r

I am using the library *sp* as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404596/converting-geo-coordinates-from-degree-to-decimal) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581838/in-r-how-to-convert-longitude-and-latitude-to-a-format-that-can-be-used-in-ggplo) to convert from degree-minute-second (dms) representation to decimal degrees(dd).

If I try the following code using *sp*, this is the result:

```
loc$Lat<-sp::char2dms(loc$Lat)
```

> Error in rep(value, length.out = nrows) : 
>       attempt to replicate an object of type 'S4'

A sample of my data is as follows:

```
    c("39d47m01s N", "15d38m08s N", "12d45m01s N", "13d17m25s N", 
    "36d34m29s N", "24d46m34s S", "11d52m39s S", "39d47m01s N", "30d52m34s N", 
    "34d59m47s S")
```

I need to convert from dms to dd as I want to calculate Haversine (great circle distances) between points.

I am also open to using other packages to do the conversion.

I tried using the library *birk* but it is giving me some meaningless answers where the lat/long are greater than 1000. Before, trying birk, I had converted the lat/long representation to one that birk accepts in its `conv_unit` function

Comment: Can you include sample data with which `conv_unit` did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be off, perhaps someone more knowledgeable than me can chime in but here goes.

I found a [thread from R-help mailing list (from 6 years ago)](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-August/249374.html) that talks about converting from DMS to decimal degrees using formula `Decimal degrees = Degrees + (Minutes/60) + (Seconds/3600)`.

Using regular expressions to find the appropriate element, I construct a data.frame which is used to apply the above mentioned formula. Multiplying coordinates from South and West by -1 to make them negative.

```
xy <- c("39d47m01s N", "15d38m08s N", "12d45m01s N", "13d17m25s N", 
  "36d34m29s N", "24d46m34s S", "11d52m39s S", "39d47m01s N", "30d52m34s N", 
  "34d59m47s S")

nxy <- data.frame(degs = as.numeric(gsub("(^\\d+)(.+$)", "\\1", xy)),
                  mins = as.numeric(gsub("(^.+d)(\\d+)(m.+$)", "\\2", xy)),
                  secs = as.numeric(gsub("(^.+m)(\\d+)(s [A-Z]$)", "\\2", xy)),
                  direction = gsub("(^.+ )([A-Z])$", "\\2", xy))

nxy$indec <- with(nxy, degs + (mins/60) + (secs/3600))

nxy[nxy$direction %in% c("W", "S"), "indec"] <- nxy[nxy$direction %in% c("W", "S"), "indec"] * -1

nxy

   degs mins secs direction     indec
1    39   47    1         N  39.78361
2    15   38    8         N  15.63556
3    12   45    1         N  12.75028
4    13   17   25         N  13.29028
5    36   34   29         N  36.57472
6    24   46   34         S -24.77611
7    11   52   39         S -11.87750
8    39   47    1         N  39.78361
9    30   52   34         N  30.87611
10   34   59   47         S -34.99639
```

Or, you could make char2dms work for you.

```
nxy$char2dms <- as.numeric(sp::char2dms(xy, chd = "d", chm = "m", chs = "s"))

   degs mins secs direction     indec  char2dms
1    39   47    1         N  39.78361  39.78361
2    15   38    8         N  15.63556  15.63556
3    12   45    1         N  12.75028  12.75028
4    13   17   25         N  13.29028  13.29028
5    36   34   29         N  36.57472  36.57472
6    24   46   34         S -24.77611 -24.77611
7    11   52   39         S -11.87750 -11.87750
8    39   47    1         N  39.78361  39.78361
9    30   52   34         N  30.87611  30.87611
10   34   59   47         S -34.99639 -34.99639
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out.

Even though `sp::char2dms` accepts arguments called `chd, chm and chs` that are supposed to let us specify the separators used for degree, minutes and seconds, they do not seem to work.

After I changed the format in which the coordinates are represented, the function is working as expected. So, I just needed to make sure that my coordinates are in the format that sp::char2dms expects by default, which is of the form:

```
15d5'52.4394" N    145d40'26.04" E
```

The seperators for degree, minute and second are d,' and " respectively.

Comment: `chd`, `chm` and `chs` work. See last part of my (edited) answer.

Comment: It did not work for me unfortunately. I spent hours trying it. But, I will accept your answer as it is more comprehensive and also has the code for calculation without libraries.

Comment: I'm working with `sp` version sp_1.2-2. Perhaps you missed a small detail?